# Selecting page size from style file

Tags: page

I would like to change the page size ulitising page sizes from a selection (Custom1 (e.g 13cmx21cm), Custom2 (e.g. 21cmx26cm)) using an option from a style file.  How can I do it ?

Comment: The geometry package can handle odd page sizes.  Or do you want to create a new document class or sty file with with new options for page size?  In that case, take and exiting cls or sty file and modify it.

Comment: I want to use a name that sets a specific size set by a General Contractor without having me set the exact values.

Comment: The easiest way is to create a new macro, such as \mypaperA and \mypaperB (which call `\geometry{paperwidth=..., paperheight=...}`  Adding new options is much more difficult.

Comment: How can I do that, a macro.

Comment: `\newcommand{\mypaperA}{\geometry{paperwidth=13cm,paperheight=21cm}}`